# Data tree rendering, editing and saving current state

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I am new to angularJS and front end development in general. I am building a data rendering tree something similar to this one I found online :

[JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/)

HTML:

```
    <script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    {{data.name}}
    <button ng-click="add(data)">Add node</button>
    <button ng-click="delete(data)" ng-show="data.nodes.length > 0">Delete nodes</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>

<ul ng-app="Application" ng-controller="TreeController">
    <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

AngularJS:

```
 angular.module("myApp", []).
controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.delete = function(data) {
        data.nodes = [];
    };
    $scope.add = function(data) {
        var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
        var newName = data.name + '-' + post;
        data.nodes.push({name: newName,nodes: []});
    };
        $scope.tree = [{name: "Node", nodes: []}];
    }]);
```

CSS:

```
 ul {
        list-style: circle;
    }
    li {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
```

The only difference is that I need user to be able to edit Nodes names from interface and It should be possible to store current state in local storage and read from it.

Comment: Do you have a question? I can't see one here.

Comment: I need help with editing each node name via interface and saving current state locally. As I told I'm new to this framework and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @ВоробьевАндрей, If you are looking for how can you communicate with server for each change in the tree(view), I can refer some useful links here. You can use [Breez.angular.js](https://breeze.github.io/doc-js/breeze-angular) for communicate with server.